# cURL PUT doesn't send the data in body

Tags: php, moodle, php-curl

So I'm making a Moodle auth plugin for our internal system. For the part of the plugin that syncs updated profile information back to the external API, I need to make a PUT request.

The problem I'm experiencing is that a part of the request is sent through, but then it just stops and eventually the curl operation times out.

My code for making the request:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
array_push($headers, 'Content-Type: application/json');
array_push($headers, 'Expect:');
array_push($headers, 'Connection: keep-alive');

if ($authtoken){
array_push($headers, 'Authorization: Bearer '.$authtoken);
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $serverurl.'/'.$functionname);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_error($curl)){
  curl_close($curl);
  return false;
}

curl_close($curl);
return $result;
```

Most of this code works as intended, as it is used for other requests as well and works fine. Specifically for PUT requests like this one, though, it sends around 614 bytes out of the total, for example 614 out of 2324, according to Fiddler, then it stops. Eventually, it times out and I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've fixed it. The solution was to change this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
```

To this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```